# Printing Picture and Text

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, picturebox

I have a form that has this interface

[image]

The form accepts data from the user in textboxes and also allows the user to load an image into a picture box. My question is that how will i enable the user to print the texts and image together the way it is in the form.

I have been able to use this code to print data in the `textboxes` and `labels`.

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string fname = txtName.Text;
        string lname = txtLname.Text;
        string mname = txtMname.Text;
        string address = txtAddress.Text;
        string gender = cmbGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string country = cmbCountry.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string data = "First Name : \t" + fname + "\n\nLast Name : \t" + lname + "\n\nMiddle Name : \t" + mname + "\n\nAddress : \t" + address + "\n\nGender : \t" + gender + "\n\nNationality : \t" + country;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
    }
```

Pls What do i need to add to enable the user print the picture along with the Text.

**NOTE :**

This is how i load a picture into the picture box

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                picCpic.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(picCpic.Image, 300, 20);`  Play with the x y values.

Comment: @LarsTech Pls where do i put it in my Code?

Comment: Right under the `e.Graphics.DrawString(...)` code you have.

Comment: If i do that. It'll print only the Image and not text

Comment: Did you try it?  You can call as many e.Graphic.Draw... calls you want inside that method.  The page is your canvas.

Comment: Yes i did. I'm using print preview to preview the document

Comment: Dennis and I seem to be telling you same thing.  Play with the left, top values of where you are placing your image in the page.  How big is the image?  You may need to resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage.aspx) method:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox.Image, new Point(10, 10));
```

Comment: Inside `printDocument1_PrintPage` from your sample.

Comment: Looks like the image overlaps text. You should play with coordinates. There's no magic in drawing. By default, all you draw overlaps things you've drawn earlier in the current drawing area.

Comment: Oh i didn't think of that..THANKS

Just used `new Point(20, 400);`